# Bootstrap Select multiselect without a dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-select

I am using Bootstrap-Select Plugin for a multi-select operation but the UI looks Different then a generic multi-select UI.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
This is what i want from bootstrap select
<select multiple class="form-control" id="sel2">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
This is what boostrap select will render.
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

I can alter the CSS or make the Bootstrap-Select open on the load but I am trying to find a generic solution which is simple and doesn't need many patches.

Comment: Yup, this should be enough!